# C - Replace tabs with spaces, multiple spaces with 1 space, multiple newlines with 1 newline

Tags: c

I'm asked to write a simple program to "format" text based on the well-known loop:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
   putchar(c);
```

The program reads from stdin & writes to stdout & should be tested using I/O redirection.

- Each tab in the input is replaced by a space & then two or more consecutive spaces are replaced by a single space in the output.
- Two or more consecutive blank lines in the input are replaced by one blank line in the output.

Note: newline character is the last character of a line rather than the first character of the following line.

Here is what I have so far, but the multiples spaces, newlines and tabs I have in my input text file aren't getting replaced in the output text file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

int c;
int spacecount = 0;
int newlinecount = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){

    if (c == '\n'){
        if (++newlinecount < 3){
            putchar(c);
        }
        continue;
    }

    newlinecount = 0;

    if (c == ' '){
        if (++spacecount < 2){
            putchar(c);
        }
        continue;   
    }

    spacecount = 0;

    if (c == '\t'){
        c = ' ';
    }
    putchar(c);
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: "Nothing is working" Can you explain what it is doing, or not doing? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it fail silently, deadlock, run as expected but not perform one or more expected changes, what?

Comment: It compiles perfectly fine. But when I try running it, the output text file is the same as the input text file. The spaces are not "squeezed" together, nor the tab is replaced by a space.

Comment: What files? Your program does not read/write any files (directly). Unless you are doing redirection on the command line. In which case you need to describe that.

Comment: @canucksfan96: Can't reproduce. When I compile and run your program, it does indeed compact the spaces. Aren't you just looking at terminal echo or something like that?

Comment: @kaylum - sorry, yeah, I'm using I/O redirection.

Comment: Please show how you are redirecting and also state clearly how you have determined that the output is wrong (did you open it and visually inspect? Or use a diff tool? or...).

Comment: The tabs are buggy, though, in case it's only that which confuses you.

Comment: @kaylum - for example in my input text file I have "Hello[space][space][space]World[newline][newline][newline][tab]This[space][space]is[newline][newline]canucksfan96" and in the output file, it should be like "Hello[space]World[newline][space]This[space]is[newline]canucksfan96"

Comment: I think it is happening bcoz your if conditions are not matching. And your last statement in loop is printing all ur data as it is. Try printing something in any of the if's statements to know that conclusion is being done correctly. You can also use debugging to know the flow of ur actual working program.

Comment: You don't need to count spaces and newlines. You just need a variable that turns them on to print first occurrence and turn them off to stop printing succeeding occurrence. You don't need a separate `if` block for tabs. in the block where you check for space, you can also check for tab. I managed to run it successfully with these modifications

Comment: @alvits that works for spaces, but not for `\n`, because multiple blank lines should be surpressed. So `\n\n` would be correct, but not `\n\n\n`. A counter is the easiest way to accomplish that.

Comment: @canucksfan96 Did you step through with a debugger to see what's happening? And please add the call from shell as suggested before.

Answer (score 2):

**Remove All Blank Lines & Compressing All Tab & Spaces to 1 Space**

The biggest problem you have is if you encounter a `' '` or a `'\n'` where you need to replace multiple occurrences of either with a smaller number, you need to keep reading (at that point within your outer `while` loop) until you find a character that is not a `' '` or a `'\n'`. That simplifies keeping track of your counts. (and eliminates the need for `spacecount` and `newlinecount`)

Since you are testing against multiple characters, when you find the first character that does not match your current search character, simply put it back in `stdin` and move to the next iteration of your outer while loop.

When compressing all `tabs` and `spaces` to a single `space`, you need to test for either a `tab` or `space` in a single `if` statement.

Putting that together, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int c;

    while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\r') continue;
        if (c == '\n') {        /* handle newlines/carriage-returns */
            putchar (c);
            while ((c = getchar ()) == '\n' || c == '\r') {}
            if (c != EOF) ungetc (c, stdin); else break;
            continue;
        }
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {  /* spaces & tabs */
            putchar (' ');
            while ((c = getchar ()) == ' ' || c == '\t') {}
            if (c != EOF) ungetc (c, stdin); else break;
            continue;
        }
        putchar (c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the code was updated to handle DOS/windoze `\r\n` line endings as well as Linux `'\n'`)

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/gcfmt.txt

N <tab> description
21      grapes
18      pickles



N <spaces> description
23         apples
51         banannas



<spaces>N<tab>  description
        8       cherries
        4       mellons
        6       strawberries


that's  all     folks   <tab separated>

that's  all     folks   <space separated>
```

**Exampe Use/Output**

Using the same input file, the output is now:

```
$ ./bin/gcfmt1 <dat/gcfmt.txt
N <tab> description
21 grapes
18 pickles
N <spaces> description
23 apples
51 banannas
<spaces>N<tab> description
 8 cherries
 4 mellons
 6 strawberries
that's all folks <tab separated>
that's all folks <space separated>
```

Let me know if that is what you intended.

Comment: I tried running your code. But in the output text file, the spaces and tabs didn't "squeeze" into one space, neither did multiple newlines "squeeze" into one newline.

Comment: Oh, right now each `tab` is replaced with `8-spaces`. (that's the reason for `#define TABSPC 8` that lets you set the number of `spaces` to replace each `tab` with) If you want any series of `tabs & spaces` squeezed into `one space`, that's a simple mod. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need.

Comment: Additionally, If you want to remove all blank lines (I collapsed multiple blank lines to `1`), all you need is `newlinecount++ < 1` above (or tailor the `if` block to mimic the block for `space`.

Comment: Hi, I saw your edited post above. I tested it and now it works where it replaces tabs and multiple spaces with a single space! Only problem is, it doesn't work for multiple newlines, where it should replace with a single newline. Do you know the problem?

Comment: Uh, if there is more than one-`'\n'` in a row, it replaces it with a *single* `'\n'`. Oh, *Are you on Winoze?* Hold on. You have `carriage-returns` to worry about. Updated to handle DOS files.

Comment: Glad to help, make sure you understand why I coded it the way I did. There is no magic about character processing in C. It is a straight-forward sequence of taking input *character-by-character* and then conditionally acting on each character. It takes a bit to get familiar with, but it is worth taking the time to learn.